# JavaScript: SetInterval doesnt work if I use position:absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I am making my own image swapper:

```
function slideImages() {
    var images = $('#frontimageswap a');

    $(images[0]).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(images[1]).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $(images[2]).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $(images[3]).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $(images[4]).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                        $(images[5]).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                });
            });
        }); 
    });
}

$(function() {
    slideImages();
    setInterval(slideImages, 12000);
});//READY
```

this works ok eg: http://jsfiddle.net/RMUta/13/

But when I add `position: absolute` to stack the images on top of each other it breaks - all the animations seem to happen all at once.

Would any one know how to fix this or why this is occurring?

Comment: Sounds like your issue is with cascaded animations, not `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually doing fine. The others are actually fading, but hidden behind the last element which is on top of the stack.

What you want to do is [fade out, the last element and place it behind the others](http://jsfiddle.net/RMUta/14/). That way, the next element (second to the last) is now on top. Think of it as putting the top card in a deck behind all others, to reveal the next card.

The routine is

```
/*
1. Fade out
2. Prepend the last element to the container.
   This moves the element to the back of the stack, since the last one is on top.
3. Show it, since fadeOut sets display:none. We need to toggle it back.
*/

var container = $('#frontimageswap');

setInterval(function () {
    //fade
    $('a:last-child', container).fadeOut(600, function () {
      $(this)
        .prependTo(container) //send to the back
        .show();              //make it visible
    });
}, 1000);
```